# How can I consistenly map a random string to an item in a variable-length set?

Tags: algorithm, hash, set

I have a blog that allows users to post anonymous comments, and I'd like to show generated icons for each user based on their userID string (user has the same icon for any of their posts in the same thread).

This would be simple if the list of icons was a static number. So if there were 100 icons, I could just hash the userID to a `number` based on a thread specific hash, and assign the user the icon `icons[number % 100]`, but I would like the ability to add more icons over time.

This presents a problem though, because now if my hashed `number` was 2102 and I have 200 icons, that commenter's icon will change from `icons[2]` to `icons[102]`, potentially confusing anyone who mentioned that poster by their icon ("red square" or whatever)

So how can I build a system to assign users icons that allows me to add assets to the pool of icons without affecting existing icon calculations?

*If you have tag suggestions, I would appreciate them*

**edit**

Because of time constraints, I am implementing this in a straightforward way of looping through the comments and assigning the commenter their previous icon, or selecting a new one at random. This operates at O(N) where N is comments length. There seems to be O(LogN) solutions, and possibly constant-time solutions, but their (implementation) complexity might not be justified since threads usually do not have thousands of comments. Still very open to other solutions.

Comment: consistent hashing? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing

Comment: If you know when the icon was generated i.e. the set size at that moment, no problem. Keep a time/generation stamp per newly added icon (icon group).

Comment: @JoopEggen For this to work, I would have to look at the other comments in the thread to see if the first comment from that user was made before the new icon set was generated. And at that rate, I might as well just comb through the comments and assign any previously used icon, or generate a random one for the first user-thread-comment. Which *is* an option I'm aware of but it operates on O(N) time instead of constant.

Comment: Somewhere you need to use/hold information, as the new icons must become eligible for usage as user icon. Some scheme like this weeks user icons are picked from the icon set a week ago, Icons added this week will be used next week. Maybe even with a shifting window of two days. Good luck.